# SQLite transactions with Google IO REST pattern's ContentProvider?

Tags: android, rest, transactions, android-contentprovider, googleio

I'm trying to implement the second REST client model presented by Virgil Dobjanschi on this video:

http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

This is the high level diagram for the model I'm talking about:

[image]

I implemented everything as suggested, but I have a complex SQLite database model with lots of tables and I need to use transactions to update my local data with brand new data retrieved from server (step 7 in the picture).

Are there any suggestions you could make to help me out implement a transactional ContentProvider for this case?

Some of you may suggest me to use raw SQLite instead, but this way I won't take the advantages of ContentObservers, managedQueries and database accesses synchronization provided by the ContentProvider.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Love that video by the way. It's really helped me understand REST.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have access to the the Level 11 API, you could do this instead. Lets say you want to do this transaction stuff in your update method:

```
final Cursor update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where, String[] selectionArgs)
{

   if(uri == uri1){
     //do stuff you normally do
   }
   //other uri stuff
   ...
   else if(uri == special_uri){
     //do your transaction stuff here
   }
}
```

In this case, `special_uri` is a uri you use to indicate that you're going to need to do your special transaction stuff. In other words, we're using the URI here to indicate that a transaction must be done.

Comment: I already considered using flags in the URI for that, but I'm expecting there is a more elegant approach. I'm sure someone here in SO have already faced this. Thank you again anyway.

Comment: You don't have to use flags. You could actually have a different URI. This isn't really that inelegant because it's still RESTful.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom function in your ContentProvider that execute your necessary transactions. Then you can call those funcitons using the [call()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#call%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) function in your Processor.

Comment: Thank you Kurtis, it could solve the problem, unless the fact it's only supported on devices running SDK >= 11. My application targets devices running Android 1.6 or greater. =(